# jQuery UI function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="square" id="drop" data-color="red"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $( ".square" ).draggable();
</script>
```

For some reason this jQuery is not working at all, and I have no idea how I could fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include jQuery UI **after** jQuery, as it's dependent on it.

```js
  $( ".square" ).draggable();
```

```css
div {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="square" id="drop" data-color="red"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Where you putting your jQuery code? At the end of the document or in the head? If it's in the head make sure you wrap it in a document.ready call. As you can see by the example in my answer, it works when you change the order.

Comment: i have it placed at the end of my document